# EXCEL VBA -Copy specific column from multi selected sheets to a new worksheet / workbook

Tags: excel, vba, multi-select

I want to extract some data from around 40-50 sheets, i know how to do if it is a single sheet. But i dont know how to extract from multi-sheet...
one point is that to choose some sheets (selected sheets) but not all because some hidden sheets i dont need to use.

if it is single sheet, my code as below,
i also tried to use "for each", but it select all of them. can anyone help for the multi-sheet selection ? Thanks

```
Sub CopyRetentionData()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim outputRow As Long

    Set wsInput = ActiveSheet

    ' Check if the Output sheet exists, if not, create it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Output")
    If wsOutput Is Nothing Then
        Set wsOutput = Worksheets.Add
        wsOutput.Name = "Output"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


    wsOutput.Cells.Clear     'Clear any previous content in the Output sheet

    lastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


    outputRow = 2

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        If InStr(1, wsInput.Cells(i, "B").Value, "Retention") > 0 Then 'Check if column B contains the word "Retention"

            wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, "A").Value = Right(wsInput.Range("D4").Value, 13)
            wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, "B").Value = wsInput.Cells(i, "C").Value
            wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, "C").Value = wsInput.Cells(i, "R").Value
         
            outputRow = outputRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation, "Operation Complete"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with using For Each but you will need to test to see if the sheet is visible (not hidden) and is selected.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And IsWSSelected(ws, wb) Then
            CopyRetentionData
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I got a function to check if a sheet is selected from [MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-if-worksheet-is-selected.193955/)

```
Function IsWSSelected(wsToTest As Worksheet, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
'Credit: Greg Truby https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-if-worksheet-is-selected.193955/
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        If ws Is wsToTest Then IsWSSelected = True: Exit Function
    Next ws
End Function
```

You will need to change where you are putting the output in your CopyRetentionData routine i.e. replace `outputRow = 2` with `outputRow = lastRow(ws) + 1`
I use the following code to find the last row in a worksheet

```
Public Function lastRow(rg As Variant) As Long
'Find the last row used in a worksheet - regardless of where the data starts and ends
'and regardless of whether the data is contiguous or jagged
'Note use of Variant for the input range parameter
'This allows both worksheets and ranges to passed into the function
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
                    , LookAt:=xlPart _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                    , SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        lr = 1  'cater for a completely empty sheet
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    lastRow = lr
End Function
```